# A debugger to show me the names of the controls on the form

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

C# WinApps:

what is a tool or debugger that I can use to see the name and values of the controls that I have drawn on the form at run time - I mean when I run my program I want to be able to use that tool and hover over controls on the form and that program show me the name and value of that control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396(VS.60).aspx)

Comment: Will Spy++ be able to figure that sort of stuff out for managed code?

Comment: yeah, underneath they're all GDI+ objects. For WPF it's a different story